# What is the average +/- % for the battery Power estimator?

Tags: power-management, battery

I'm using an
HP Elitebook 8460p with NEW Battery.
8GB-mem 250GB-storage
i5-2520M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
HD Graphics 3000 (SNB GT2)
GNOME 3.28.2
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 32-bit.

What is the average +/- % for the battery Power estimator?
The estimate jumps around immediately after I've unplugged the power adapter.
*For example*, it jumps from 4 hours 10 minutes to 2 hours 38 minutes and then back to 3 hours 14 minutes in about a 25 to 45 second time period.
I never really know how much time I really have on the battery.
Why would this happen?
Thank you for your help.

Shobuz99

Comment: Barring the existence of some scientific study that addresses this exact question, this is not a question that can be answered with anything but speculation and guessing.  Perhaps you should research if and how you might calibrate the battery. Every device is different.

Comment: I just wanted to know if it's something to do with the hardware or instead, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
"Every device is different" makes sense; but I wanted to know if anyone already knows the quantified variance to expect. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime estimation is the quotient of remaining battery charge in Wh and the current power draw in W, averaged over a short timespan of maybe 5 to 15 secs. The actual power draw may change very quickly depending on your usage or workload.

The momentary estimate is therefore completely useless for finding out what you want to know, namely the expected total runtime for your typical usage.

In fact you will have to use the battery a few times until empty and record the runtime manually.

EDIT: also there is no way to "calibrate" the estimation.